# How to integrate OpenRTSP-live555 library into my android application

Tags: android, live555

I want to use openRtsp-live555 library into my android application for the RTSP but i am not getting how to include it in my project and how to compile so that i can use it's methods in my Acivity or java class.

Please Help me if anybody has used Live555 library or know how to use it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Live555 is a C++ library and you must have some knowledge with the Android NDK to make use of it.

An example of Live555 integration can be found [here](https://github.com/boltonli/ohbee/tree/master/android/streamer) (AFAIK, this is the only open-source one). It has not been updated since years, but it is not hard to update with the [last Live555 sources](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/public/live555-latest.tar.gz).

More guidelines in the [Live555 faq](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/faq.html#custom).